# pass xdocument elements (not element) as string

Tags: vb.net, variables, linq-to-xml, element

I am trying to find out the total number of elements of a specific name that exist in an Xml document using VB. Should be a simple enough task but I've hit a problem.

I can make the following code work but can't pass the element name as a string (In the original code I am doing this from an array that I want to loop through), I don't receive an error in visual studio, at compile time or during run time, it just returns zero quantity.
I have cut the original code down to show just the section I am having an issue with.

The following code works.

```
    Dim xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("c:\test\xmlFile.xml")
    myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Elements.<AIOWEB_tPriceBand>.Count()
    MsgBox(myXMLRowCount)
```

The only example I can find for passing a variable as the element is by removing the .<> and replacing with (myVariable) - as the code below shows, but the example I have seen this on is for Element not Elements and doesn't appear to work the same (unless I'm missing a step / character in the command structure).

```
    Dim xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("c:\test\xmlFile.xml")
    Dim myXmlElement As String = "AIOWEB_tPriceBand"
    myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(myXmlElement).Count()
    MsgBox(myXMLRowCount)
```

- edit *

Here's a cut down example of one of the xml files in question.
I have tested it here with the above lines of code and again the direct reference works (shows 5 elements) but the second example with the variable returns 0 elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:od="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:officedata">
    <xsd:schema>
        <xsd:element name="dataroot">
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element ref="AIOWEB_tPriceBand" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:attribute name="generated" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="AIOWEB_tPriceBand">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo>
                    <od:index index-name="ProductCode" index-key="ProductCode " primary="no" unique="no" clustered="no"/>
                </xsd:appinfo>
            </xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:complexType>
                <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element name="ProductCode" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="text" od:sqlSType="nvarchar">
                        <xsd:simpleType>
                            <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
                                <xsd:maxLength value="50"/>
                            </xsd:restriction>
                        </xsd:simpleType>
                    </xsd:element>
                    <xsd:element name="MinQty" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="longinteger" od:sqlSType="int" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="MaxQty" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="longinteger" od:sqlSType="int" type="xsd:int"/>
                    <xsd:element name="UnitPrice" minOccurs="0" od:jetType="currency" od:sqlSType="money" type="xsd:double"/>
                </xsd:sequence>
            </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:schema>
    <dataroot xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" generated="2014-01-16T12:02:35">
        <AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
            <ProductCode>0000000000001</ProductCode>
            <MinQty>1</MinQty>
            <MaxQty>0</MaxQty>
            <UnitPrice>0.01</UnitPrice>
        </AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
        <AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
            <ProductCode>0000000000002</ProductCode>
            <MinQty>1</MinQty>
            <MaxQty>0</MaxQty>
            <UnitPrice>0.01</UnitPrice>
        </AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
        <AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
            <ProductCode>0000000000003</ProductCode>
            <MinQty>1</MinQty>
            <MaxQty>0</MaxQty>
            <UnitPrice>0.01</UnitPrice>
        </AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
        <AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
            <ProductCode>0000000000004</ProductCode>
            <MinQty>1</MinQty>
            <MaxQty>0</MaxQty>
            <UnitPrice>0.01</UnitPrice>
        </AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
        <AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
            <ProductCode>0000000000005</ProductCode>
            <MinQty>1</MinQty>
            <MaxQty>0</MaxQty>
            <UnitPrice>0.01</UnitPrice>
        </AIOWEB_tPriceBand>
    </dataroot>
</root>
```

Comment: It works for me.  Can you post an example XML document that can be used to reproduce the behavior?

Comment: Hi Steve, I will get one of the smaller documents, cut it down to maybe 5 records and strip out the sensitive info. Thanks

Comment: Hi Steve, I have added the Xml example to my original post. Thanks

Comment: Can you also update the example VB code so that it uses the correct element name that you are trying to count?

Comment: Hi Steve, I have added the correct element name to the above code. This is now the same as the code I have been testing. Thanks - Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `AIOWEB_tPriceBand` elements are not located directly under the `root` element.  Instead, they are actually located under the `/root/dataroot` element.

The reason that the first code sample works is because it is reading the `xmlDoc.Root.Elements.<AIOWEB_tPriceBand>` elements.  You'll notice that it is not accessing the `AIOWEB_tPriceBand` elements directly under `Root`.  Instead, it's accessing them from `Root.Elements`, which is actually the collection of all of the child elements of the `Root` element.  Since `dataroot` is a child of the `Root` element, it will look for them under there.  To make the first code sample mimic the second one, you would have needed to write it this way:

```
' Won't work because it looks for /root/AIOWEB_tPriceBand
myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.<AIOWEB_tPriceBand>.Count()
```

The less confusing way to have written it, to make it work properly, would have been like this:

```
' Will work because it looks for /root/dataroot/AIOWEB_tPriceBand
myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.<dataroot>.<AIOWEB_tPriceBand>.Count()
```

Now that it's more clear why it was that the first example was actually working, now it should be more clear how to get the second example to work:

```
myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.<dataroot>.Elements(myXmlElement).Count()
```

Alternatively, if you don't care where, exactly, in the document structure, that the `AIOWEB_tPriceBand` elements actually exist, and all you want to do is get a total count of them, where ever in the document they happen to be, then you can simply search for any descendants of the root by that name, rather than specifying the path down through the `dataroot` element:

```
myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root...<AIOWEB_tPriceBand>.Count()
```

Or, by string:

```
myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants(myXmlElement).Count()
```

I should also mention that you really ought to be using `MessageBox.Show` rather than the old VB6-style `MsgBox` method.

Comment: Thanks Steve, That works perfectly.  It was really driving me mad, just couldn't see the problem. (I've changed any Msgbox statements to MessageBox btw - guess I'm showing my age ... time for a retrain.

Comment: @user3203148 If you are interested in forcing yourself off of the VB6 style commands (which are included in .NET primarily for backwards compatability), you may want to try, as a learning experiment, removing the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace from your project settings "Imported Namespaces".  That's the namespace where all those things are housed.  Unfortunately, there are some new .NET only things that are also in that namespace, so ditching use of the namespace entirely isn't always an option, but it's a good way to force yourself off the VB-specific stuff.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I will give that a go and see how I get on

Comment: @user3203148 No problem.  Welcome to StackOverflow, by the way!

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of `myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Elements(myXmlElement).Count()` you want `myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Element("dataroot").Elements(myXmlElement).Count()`, to match the hierarchy in your input sample. Or you need at least `myXMLRowCount = xmlDoc.Root.Elements().Elements(myXmlElement).Count()`.